# Using 7pin OLED 128x64 with iic

Tags: arduino, i2c, display, diagram, oled

I just bought the [0.96” Monochrome OLED Display (SSD1306)](https://quartzcomponents.com/products/0-96-monochrome-oled-display-ssd1306?_pos=1&_sid=99264004d&_ss=r)  and it claims to support both SPI and IIC/I2C with ***7 pins***.

I want to use it with an Arduino Uno R3.

[image: OLED front]

[image: OLED rear]

How do I go about doing this and ensure I don't *fry* it?

Please give me a circuit diagram and tell me which pin to connect where and which pins to ignore to make it function with an Arduino Uno R3 using IIC mode.

Also do I use the same library I would use for a ***4 pins*** OLED display??

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164680/ssd1306-display-spi-connection-or-i2c-according-to-resistors) question, which has a complete answer.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that person is using 'ATmega8' with different ports
also i found [link](https://simple-circuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/arduino-ssd1306-oled-128x64-circuit.jpg) this but i am unsure of its reliablity

Comment: The I2C conversion of the PCB may be on-topic here (although arguably it is not). Questions about software libraries are best referred to the Arduino SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Connections

D0 is the clock line and D1 is the data line, which is true for both SPI and I<sup>2</sup>C.

Connections to the Arduino Uno (using hardware SPI):

- D0 => SCK
- D1 => MOSI
- CS => any IO pin
- DC => any IO pin
- RST => any IO pin

The SMD resistors should have 0 Ohm values. To change from SPI to I<sup>2</sup>C:

- Unsolder R3
- Solder R8 and R1

You do not need to use zero ohm resistors, just connect the two pads.

*As a sanity check that the unit is actually working, test the OLED with the current SPI configuration first. This will ensure that the unit is actually working before you start soldering away*.

##### Library

You can use the same library. For example, if you use `U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64`, just uncomment the relevant line:

```
//U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(13, 11, 10, 9); // SW SPI Com: SCK = 13, MOSI = 11, CS = 10, A0 = 9
//U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(4, 5, 6, 7);    // SW SPI Com: SCK = 4, MOSI = 5, CS = 6, A0 = 7 (new white HalTec OLED)
//U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(10, 9);     // HW SPI Com: CS = 10, A0 = 9 (Hardware Pins are  SCK = 13 and MOSI = 11)
//U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(U8G_I2C_OPT_NONE|U8G_I2C_OPT_DEV_0);    // I2C / TWI 
//U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(U8G_I2C_OPT_DEV_0|U8G_I2C_OPT_NO_ACK|U8G_I2C_OPT_FAST); // Fast I2C / TWI 
//U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(U8G_I2C_OPT_NO_ACK);    // Display which does not send AC
```

##### Further reading

- [Running a 7 pin OLED with 4 pins (I2C)](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/running-a-7-pin-oled-with-4-pins-i2c/469007)

Answer (score 1):

As it says on the PCB, R3 and R4 need to be fitted (which they are) to allow 4-wire SPI operation.  For I2C you’d need to change the resistor configuration.
The markings on the top surface of the PCB indicate the pinout for SPI operation but not for I2C.  Really your best option is to track down a datasheet for this board and see what it has to say.